# What am I doing wrong in drawing a line in wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

// cMain.cpp

```
#include "cMain.h"

cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "ImProcGUI", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(800, 600)) {

    m_MenuBar = new wxMenuBar();
    // File Menu
    m_FileMenu = new wxMenu();
    m_FileMenu->Append(wxID_OPEN, _T("&Open"));
    m_FileMenu->Append(wxID_OPEN, _T("&Save"));
    m_FileMenu->Append(wxID_OPEN, _T("&Quit"));
    m_MenuBar->Append(m_FileMenu, _T("&File"));

    // About Menu
    m_HelpMenu = new wxMenu();
    m_HelpMenu->Append(wxID_ABOUT, _T("&About"));
    m_MenuBar->Append(m_HelpMenu, _T("&Help"));

    SetMenuBar(m_MenuBar);

}

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cMain, wxFrame)
    EVT_PAINT(cMain::OnPaint)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()


cMain::~cMain() {

}

void cMain::onPaint(wxPaintEvent& event) {
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    wxCoord x1 = 50, y1 = 60;
    wxCoord x2 = 190, y2 = 60;

    dc.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

// cMain.h

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

class cMain : public wxFrame
{
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();
    wxWindow* m_Window = nullptr;
    wxMenuBar* m_MenuBar = nullptr;
    wxMenu* m_FileMenu = nullptr;
    wxMenu* m_HelpMenu = nullptr;

    void onPaint(wxPaintEvent& event);
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

Above is the code I have. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a main frame, onto which I want to draw. When I run the code, however, the line is not there. (in my first attempt, I tried to put a window onto the frame and to draw onto it, but the line was not there in that case too)

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing on the frame, but your entire frame is covered by `m_Window`, which hides whatever you draw. You probably don't need this window at all, but if you do, you need to draw on it, not on the frame itself.

Also note that you're using *both* the event table and `Connect()` with your handler, which is not catastrophic, but still wrong and, at best, useless. Use one *or* the other, or, better, use `Bind()` (rather than `Connect()`).

Moreover, you've made a typo in your handler name: you used `OnPaint()` in `EVT_PAINT` macro, which just happens to be the name of a base class handler doing nothing, rather than your `onPaint()`. So your handler is not called at all.

Comment: Commented `w_Window` out and also removed `Connect()` but still the same issue. What do you suggest? Maybe my approach is wrong in the first place - meaning, `wxPaintDC` needs something else?

Comment: Looking _very_ carefully at your code, I've noticed that you made a typo in the method name, see the updated answer.

Comment: Can you point out which method name it was or where it was? comparing my original code to this, I dont see any type. Also, I am using Visual Studio which says everything is OK?

Comment: I've updated the explanation, but you could just search your code for `OnPaint`.